# redirecting/reloading page in js.erb instead of controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

My index.js.erb is refreshing the page only partially:

```
$("#view").html("<%= escape_javascript render 'view' %>");
```

I am able to refresh it fully in the controller with this line:

```
format.js { render :js => "window.location.replace('#{url_for(:controller => :view, :action => :index, :some_parameter => value)}');" }
```

Is it possible to refresh the page in js.erb?

edit:
I call index.js.erb by this command in the controller:

```
format.js { redirect_to(:action => :index, :format => :js, :some_parameter => value)},
```

It refreshes the page with the content for some_parameter, but refreshes it only partially.

window.location works better, but I read in one of stack overflow posts that it is better to use erb than controller for javascript. Is it really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second way, you're refreshing the whole page( made another http request ) and if you want to do this, why not just use `redirect_to`?

Comment: I tried to use format.js { redirect_to(:action => :index, :format => :js, :some_parameter => value)}, but it was ignoring the parameter and refreshing the page only partially, window.location.replace refreshes the page fully. I thought the reason redirect_to does not work is my index.js.erb

Comment: You don't need format.js. just redirect to the  url. Something like `redirect_to :action => :index`

Comment: I use format.js to render index.js.erb, it does some additional work that is needed. If I replace format.js with just redirect_to it does not refresh the page at all

Comment: The browser expects to receive javascript, so I can't render a HTTP redirect with just redirect_to and the answer to my question is probably no, it's best to redirect in the controller by sanding back Javascript. Thanks, xdazz.